# Layout does not load when creating a new tool in Laravel Nova

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

When I create a tool in Laravel Nova with

```
php artisan nova:tool drehimself/test-tool
```

And then add in `NovaServiceProvider.php` in the function tools, should appear a layout where showed a black hole. Only that when I press the option that appears in the menu on the left side, it shows nothing, not even the url changes.

Does anyone know what it could be?

Comment: You need to make your own tool. What do you really expect?

Comment: Yes I do, because of some APIs @WahyuKristianto

Comment: You need to explain in more detail the extent of what you are doing. If you ask about nova tool, it is completely in your control, what you want to build is up to you.

Comment: I know, by default the page should come with the address and a default layout like this. [Image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/2741290/68753133-872a5600-0615-11ea-9bf3-df7ba7735136.png) But when I do the artisan, mine doesn't look like this.

Answer (score 1):

Nova tools are customizable, as they primarily consist of a single-file Vue component that is totally under your control. Within your Vue component, you are free to make HTTP requests to any controller within your application.

> By default the page should come with the address and a default layout like this. Image But when I do the artisan, mine doesn't look like this
> [image]

You need to compile your assets first.

Go to your tool :

```
cd nova-components/TestTool
```

Then :

```
# Compile your assets for local development...
npm run dev

# Compile and minify your assets...
npm run prod
```

In addition, you may run the NPM `watch` command to auto-compile your assets when they are changed:

```
npm run watch
```

Refresh, you will see your tool now.

Comment: When I do `npm run watch` I get this error
[Image](https://www.linkpicture.com/q/Error.jpg)

Comment: Idk using windows. But, did you run `npm install` on tool path before?

Comment: Yes, probably is a windows problem. A lot of people have the same problem.